# set ggplot bar width but in absolute size e.g. 1cm

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am preparing a longer report that uses many ggplot bar charts. Since the number of bars change, the bar width also changes, and it doesn't look nice. The documentation says, the bar width is set to 90% of the resolution by default. I want to know if there is a way to set an absolute width size, e.g. 1cm or 0.5inch.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956442/automatically-resize-bars-in-ggplot-for-uniformity-across-several-graphs-r?rq=1

Comment: I wish there were an answer to this; I have a lot of difficulty with this, as by changing the output resolution and dimensions the element sizes (e.g., text size, line widths, point sizes) do not scale, and in order to have nice plots I have to experiment with different values and visually inspect the saved plots. It's gruesome :(.